# Create indicator matrix for much larger data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have following data:

```
movies.head()
```

[image]

and would like to create a categorical matrix based on its genres.
The final result should look like this:

[image]

I know how to do it using a SLOW way, which is:

```
all_genres = []
for x in movies.genres:
    all_genres.extend(x.split('|'))
genres = pd.unique(all_genres)
genres
```

Output is:

```
array(['Animation', "Children's", 'Comedy', 'Adventure', 'Fantasy',
       'Romance', 'Drama', 'Action', 'Crime', 'Thriller', 'Horror',
       'Sci-Fi', 'Documentary', 'War', 'Musical', 'Mystery', 'Film-Noir',
       'Western'], dtype=object)
```

Creating a zero matrix and renaming its column to be the genres:

```
zero_matrix = np.zeros((len(movies), len(genres)))
dummies = pd.DataFrame(zero_matrix, columns=genres)
dummies.head()
```

Output is:
[image]

Converting `movies.genres` into categorical matrix:

```
for i, gen in enumerate(movies.genres):
    indices = dummies.columns.get_indexer(gen.split('|'))
    dummies.iloc[i, indices] = 1
movies_windic = movies.join(dummies.add_prefix('Genre'))
movies_windic.iloc[0:2]
```

Output is:

[image]

The above code is copied from the book Python for Data Analysis 2nd edition page 213, 214.

What irritates me is the warning under the code regarding its performance, which is

> For much larger data, this method of constructing indicator variables
> with multiple membership is not especially speedy. It would be
> betterto write a lower-level function that writes directly to a NumPy
> array,and then wrap the result in a DataFrame.

Could someone give me a pointer how to do it with a lower-level function so that it could work faster?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You mentioned that you know how to do it the slow way just above the genre for-loop. Im terms of overall performance, is it specifically the for-loop to get all unique genres that is problematic? If so, I would recommend using a set(), and add to that, since it does not store duplicate items, and will thus not become extremely long, unlike your list. This should speed it up, although how much is unclear to me (good job using .extend() and not .append() though).

Comment: wouldn't it be sufficient to create the new dataframe based on a groupby statement in conjunction with reset_index() such as `cat_df = df.groupby('category').count().reset_index()`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's generate some random data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Movie_number": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "genres": ["A|B|C", "B", "B|C", "C", "A|C"]})
print(df)
```

```
   Movie_number genres
0             1  A|B|C
1             2      B
2             3    B|C
3             4      C
4             5    A|C
```

I've managed to come up with this horrible solution:

```py
newdf = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['genres'].str.split('|').explode(), prefix="genre")], axis=1).groupby(["Movie_number", "genres"]).sum().reset_index()

print(newdf)
```

```
   Movie_number genres  genre_A  genre_B  genre_C
0             1  A|B|C        1        1        1
1             2      B        0        1        0
2             3    B|C        0        1        1
3             4      C        0        0        1
4             5    A|C        1        0        1
```

Explanation:

First we explode our `"genres"` column based on `|` separator:

```py
>>> df['genres'].str.split('|').explode()
0    A
0    B
0    C
1    B
2    B
2    C
3    C
4    A
4    C
Name: genres, dtype: object
```

Then we convert these into indicator variables with `pd.get_dummies`:

```py
>>> pd.get_dummies(df['genres'].str.split('|').explode(), prefix="genre")
   genre_A  genre_B  genre_C
0        1        0        0
0        0        1        0
0        0        0        1
1        0        1        0
2        0        1        0
2        0        0        1
3        0        0        1
4        1        0        0
4        0        0        1
```

After that we concatenate it with the original dataframe, then finally we merge the rows with `groupby` and `sum`.

```py
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['genres'].str.split('|').explode(), prefix="genre")],axis=1).groupby(["Movie_number", "genres"]).sum().reset_index()

   Movie_number genres  genre_A  genre_B  genre_C
0             1  A|B|C        1        1        1
1             2      B        0        1        0
2             3    B|C        0        1        1
3             4      C        0        0        1
4             5    A|C        1        0        1
```

Despite it's not so low-level, I think it is definitely faster than using for loops.